# Derived Category idea from ncatlab

Tags: homotopy-theory, abelian-categories, derived-categories

I have a question about following statement
from ncatlab about derived categories: (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+category#idea)

> Often in the literature, the term
> *derived category* refers to the
> homotopy category, viewed *only* as a
> triangulated category. The loss of
> information can often be problematic,
> but for many purposes is not important.

I not understand which part of structure
exactly get qualitatively lost if we
regard a certain homotopy theory
"only as a triangulated category"? If $D(A)$ (for certian Abelain category $A$) is our derived category, which homotopy theory $H$ is meant here? $K(A)$?
And is that a kind of application of certain
forgetful functor? But what
gets exactly lost here?

Recall how a derived category is
constructed: we start with an Abelian
category $A$, form the category
category of chain complexes $Com(A)$ with
terms in $A$. Next we can proceed in two
ways (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_category#Definition):

1. Localize $Com(A)$ directly with respect
   the quasi-isomorphisms (= morphisms
   inducing isomorphisms between (co)homologies
   of two chain complexes)
2. Localize firstly $Com(A)$ with respect
   homotopies in $Com(A)$ (call this new
   homotopy category $K(A)$ ) and then localize
   $K(A)$ as in 1 with respect quasi-isomorphisms.

We observe that this two construction
give the same category - call it the derived
category of $A$
$D(A)$ -
because homotopic maps are quasi-isomorphisms. Therefore $D(A)$ has intrinsical structure
of a homotopy category and I'm wondering
how it can be "forgotten" as suggested in
the statement above.

Back to my question: What is exactly in this context
the homotopy theory, which viewed only
as a triangulated category becomes our
derived category $D(A)$? The intermediate
category $K(A)$ from step 2?

It is known that there is a canonical way to endow
$D(R)$ with structure of a triangulated
category, and looking closely in the single steps of the construction one sees
that this construction exploits only the
homotopy structure of $D(R)$ - therefore already
$K(A)$ can be endowed with structure of a
triangulated category verbatim in the same way.

Is this $K(A)$ exactly *the* homotopy category
which is mentioned in the quoted text which
gives $D(R)$ if we regard it as triangulated
category "only". On the other hand which amount of structure of $K(A)$ gets
then really lost?

Comment: I think they are trying to draw the distinction between its life as a category and as an $(\infty, 1)$-category.

Comment: You mean that the mysterious homotopy category  which emerges in the text is that one which is obtained if we regard $D(R)$ via nerve functor as $ (\infty, 1)$-category and then the homotopy theory in the text is exactly that one which one can always canonically associate to any $ (\infty, 1)$-category in natural way in sense of (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+category+of+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-category#idea)?

Comment: Beats me.  I never rely on nLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $(\mathcal C, W)$ is a category with weak equivalences, you can construct an $\infty$-category $L_W\mathcal C$ via simplicial localisation. In our case, the category with weak equivalences that we consider is $(\operatorname{Com}(\mathcal A), \mathrm{qiso.})$. The associated simplicial localisation is called the derived $\infty$-category of $\mathcal A$, and the homotopy category of this $\infty$-category is the ordinary derived category $\operatorname{D}(\mathcal A)$.

Comment: So this construction identifies $D(A)$
as the homotopy category of
$\infty$-category $L_W (Com(A))$ as you said.
So $D(A)$ *is* a homotopy category. On the 
other hand in the quoted text is
said that "derived category refers to the 
homotopy category, viewed only as a 
triangulated category."

Comment: What is precisely
going lost if we "take a homotopy category 
and view it only as a triangulated category".
And how is it related concretely to the construction
in your answer?

Comment: I think the author just refers to the loss of information by passing from the $\infty$-category to its underlying homotopy category.

Comment: I see. And when the author there talks about so called "derived (infinity,1)-category" he means the simplicial localization $L_W(Com(A))$, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.